# NodeJs + MongoDB: return the document by it parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my structure of MongoDB:

[image: MongoDB structure]

I wanna make a query that return all keys and values of 1 Document in the database. I should select the document where a key "content-transition" is "ciao".
This is my code:

```
var router = express.Router();

const MongoCient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dbName = 'myproject';
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

router.get('/get/:id', function (req, res) { 

  var param = req.params.id;

  var myQuery = {
    "content-transition":param
  };

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    var collection = client.db(dbName).collection('documents');
    var result = collection.find({myQuery});
    console.log(result)
  });

});
```

I want return in the console the document into the variable "result" in relation by input parameter.
This code is written in NodeJs with che ExpressJs library.

Answer (score 1):

if `myQuery` is defined as `{ "content-transition": param }`,

and you're calling `collection.find({myQuery})`,

then what you're really doing is

```
collection.find({ myQuery: { "content-transition": param }});
```

and of course mongo has no idea what to do with that.

try removing the curly brackets around `myQuery` when you call `collection.find()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your syntax is correct but I don't return my Document.

Comment: you're also not passing a callback to [`collection.find`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) and you're not doing anything with the cursor returned by `collection.find`.  this function is asynchronous; you have to wait somehow for it to do its job.

Comment: I must append the .pretty() to find() ?